# Set Value of spinner from Array in strings.xml

Tags: android

I have a spinner, that uses an array from strings.xml

if the array has 5 strings (1,2,3,4,5), and i want the spinner to show second
string (2) as default value, is this possible?
I know i can re-arrange the strings order so that first one is 2,
but this doesn't look very good if spinner dialog appears as (2,1,3,4,5).

Or does the array have to be created within my activity programatically
and then use setPostion()?
I have tried this, but get a fault when creating array in activity.
Can anyone please give me an example of how to create array and use
it in spinner()

I have also searched on here for answers but cant seem to find what i need.

Thanks for looking....

Answer (score 12):

I recommend you check: http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-spinner.html

You should create an ArrayAdapter in your Activity.

From the above link:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
            this, R.array.planets_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

You can use

```
spinner.setSelection(adapter.getPosition(value)));
```

to set the position.

Answer (score 3):

Cheers for reply.....

Didn't do what i needed, but have managed to solve my problem as follows..

First i created an array within my activity, instead of strings.xml.

```
    String[] NoCore_Array = new String [5];
{ 
    NoCore_Array[0] = "1";
    NoCore_Array[1] = "2";
    NoCore_Array[2] = "3";
    NoCore_Array[3] = "4";
    NoCore_Array[4] = "5";

}
```

Then i created the spinner using...

```
    Spinner spnNoCore = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_nocore);
```

Then created the adapter, using above array....

```
    ArrayAdapter NoCoreAdapter =  new ArrayAdapter(this, 
    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,  NoCore_Array);
    spnNoCore.setAdapter(NoCoreAdapter);
```

Then set default position of the adapter as follows...

```
    //Set Default Selection
    spnNoCore.setSelection(1);
```

Then rest of spinner code for actions...

```
     spnNoCore.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener(){

        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,
            View view, int pos, long id) {

            //Get item from spinner and store in string conductorSize........
            NoCore = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();

            if (NoCore.equals(NoCore1))   { CoreNo = 1    ;  }
            if (NoCore.equals(NoCore2))   { CoreNo = 2    ;  }
            if (NoCore.equals(NoCore3))   { CoreNo = 3    ;  }
            if (NoCore.equals(NoCore4))   { CoreNo = 4    ;  }
            if (NoCore.equals(NoCore5))   { CoreNo = 5    ;  }

     }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView parent) {
          // Do nothing.
        }
    });
```

Hope this may help other people who are having same problem with
setting default selection on Spinner.

However the layout of the dialog is not as good when done this way,
Radio buttons are missing, just looks like a text selection
with lines dividing the sections.

Comment: thanx man , u dont know how much work u just saved me , i was trying so many useless solutions , like creating rotating arrays

Comment: @Coops5575, the fact that the dialog in your solution does not have radio buttons is due to you creating the adapter with simple_spinner_item instead if simple_spinner_dropdown_item, that's all.