# Setting the value of the spinner dynamically

Tags: java, android, eclipse, spinner, arrays

I have an `ArrayAdapter` as follows

```
ArrayAdapter<String>dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
```

This is the adapter which I am going to use for my `Spinner`.I have value sets (String array) for the `Spinner` in my `strings.xml` file.

How can I set the `<string-array>` in `string.xml` to the spinner pragmatically? Please help!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8509488/set-value-of-spinner-from-array-in-strings-xml

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add it to your ArrayAdapter when you create it.

```
String[] yourArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.array_name);

ArrayAdapter<String>dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, yourArray);
```

Comment: We need to pass texview id as well.                                
 ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),R.layout.row_spinner_text,R.id.tv_spinner_value, dataArray);

Answer (score 4):

You can try something like this :

```
String[] mTestArray;
ArrayAdapter<String>dataAdapter;

mTestArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.testArray);
dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,mTestArray);
```

and then attach the adapter to the Spinner.

```
spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
```

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. I really appreciate it! +1 from me :)

Answer (score 2):

```
spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);  
String[] itemNames = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.stringArrayName); 

   for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) // Maximum size of i upto --> Your Array Size 
    {  
    dataAdapter.add(itemNames[i]);  
     } 

spinner2.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to load data from web service and set that data in your spinner you can use this bellow code:-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Spinner spinner;
    List<String> usersList;
    ArrayAdapter<String> catAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        usersList = new ArrayList<String>();

        catAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, usersList);
        spinner.setAdapter(catAdapter);

        getHttpResponse();

    }

    public void getHttpResponse() {

        String url = "https://cakeapi.trinitytuts.com/api/listuser";

        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(url)
                .header("Accept", "application/json")
                .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
                .build();

        client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                String mMessage = e.getMessage().toString();
                Log.w("failure Response", mMessage);
                //call.cancel();
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {

                final String mMessage = response.body().string();

                MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Log.e("Response", mMessage);
                        try {
                            JSONObject users = new JSONObject(mMessage);
                            JSONArray usersArr = users.getJSONArray("users");

                            for(int i =0; i < usersArr.length(); i++){
                                JSONObject user = usersArr.getJSONObject(i);
                                Log.e("user", user.getString("username"));
                                usersList.add(user.getString("username"));
                            }

                            catAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
}
```

You can read complete information in this post:- [Add dynamic data to spinner](https://trinitytuts.com/add-dynamic-data-to-spinner-in-android-application/)

Answer (score 1):

This tutorial: [Android Spinners](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html) points out that you would use the following code to set the Spinner array based on a resource:

```
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> dataAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
    R.array.string-array-id, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
dataAdapter .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Using the `createFromResource()` method instead of `new` and providing the resource ID of your array should provide the intended result. See the tutorial for more details.

Comment: But the question specifically asks about doing this pragmatically/dynamically (i.e. not storing values in resource file, but possibly fetched at runtime). I don't see how this answers the question.